# How to simplify the versioning and hot swapping of SiteAssets?

Tags: deployment, versioning

I notice a peculiarity in SharePoint.  If I have links that point to some asset be it an image or a JavaScript, and I rename the folder containing that asset, the links (wherever they may be) tend to be updated to match the new path.  This can be useful, but not always.

When I deploy updates to SharePoint I basically treat the site as a filesystem and access it via PowerShell or more directly with Windows Explorer.  I thought it would be nice to do SiteAsset versioning.  Basically, I would deploy a new folder named `SiteAssets-v2`.  I would then rename `SiteAssets` to `SiteAssets-v1` and finally `SiteAssets-v2` to `SiteAssets`.

I learned this procedure years ago from a tool called [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) in the Ruby world.  It provides a convenient way of managing deployments.  If you notice a problem as of the latest deployment, you can quickly and easily rollback to a prior version.  Capistrano uses symlinks, but symlinks aren't necessary.  (I couldn't make them work with SharePoint.)

The trouble is that it appears to me SharePoint watches for folder renames and updates any links that once pointed to the former path to the new one.  This works against hot swapping.  I need the links to remain unchanged even if they are broken for a second or two.

What's to be done?

There is a strong appeal to being able to flip a switch to select the active version -- something that doesn't involve sychronizing files (e.g. robocopy or WSP deployments).  I want a simple, near-instantaneous way of activating a version given the fact that a history of versions is already deployed.

Comment: Interesting requirement, but I can understand your need. Out of curiosity, have you tried renaming the folder using either PowerShell or SPD besides the normal SP's UI?

Comment: Some of our sites are firewalled/secured and I can only access them in SharePoint Designer.  The other sites are available on the network but only the SiteAssets folder is directly accessible, not the root.

Answer (score 0):

With a little more thought I arrived at an obvious and comparable approach.

Use version control instead.  For each deployment, mark the release in version control.  We use TFS.  In TFS this is accomplished with a label.  The same concept in other version control systems is called a tag.

The trade off is that since the releases aren't on the servers, switching versions isn't instantaneous.  It involves a reconciliation step.  We use PowerShell and RoboCopy for this.

I use git personally.  If git were, in addition to developer machines, installed on the SharePoint servers a near instantaneous hot swap would be possible.